# Weighted Matrix Factorization

Tags: pca, svd, weighted, matrix-factorization, objective-function

So I have got this weird function which can be formulated in to objective function as shown on  [the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDmkM.png). I do know I can't use any L2 Low rank matrix factorization(LRMF) algorithms to solve this as this is considered a weighted Low rank matrix factorization(LRMF). I have looked at Iterative reweighted least square and Weighted principal component analysis but unfortunately they are available in matlab only. Any one knows any python functions I can use to solve this problem? My project does not require me to write a L2 LRMF algorithm and merely requires me to solve it using any existing functions. Any help would be ideal.

Comment: defining LRMF, IRLS, WPCA would help to make this question more appealing. Also, does the circled dot notation denote Hadamard product? Or something else?

Comment: I edited the question and defined the keywords. Yes it is hadamard product.